# How to show author name only on a post - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This code should probably be a LOT smaller, but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I want:

```
[when the visitor is on a post]
Written by: the magnificent author of this piece

[When the visitor is on anything else then a post] 
...... (nothing here)
```

Simply put:

> **This is the titel!!**
>
> Written by the magnificent author *(I only want this to show on a post, not on > a page or any other page)*
>
> The text in the article is then shown here as normal. Regardless if
>   the author is shown or not.

This is the code I've got so far...

```
<?php

if (is_single() || is_page()) {
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();

        # page + post
        wikiwp_get_thumbnail($post);

        # post only
        if (is_single()) {
?>
                            <?php
                            _e('<p>Written by:', 'wikiwp');
                            echo '&nbsp;';
                            the_author_posts_link();
                            ?>
<?php
        } else if (is_page()) {
Stuff that is shown when they are on a page
?>
<?php
        }
    endwhile;
} else {
The stuff that is shown when they are on anything else
?>
<?php
}
?>
The text of the article......
```

I'm pretty sure the code above doesn't make any sense.... But my limited PHP experience isn't really helping lol.

Comment: Where have you placed this code and also, which theme are you using - does it have a single.php file?

Comment: I haven't placed the code yet because I'm not confident that it will work properly. I'm using WikiWP theme for Wordpress. The theme does have a Singe.PHP file, but it refers to a seperate file called "content.php". Withint this content file, the content is received from the DB.
This file is used by page.php, single.php, and categorie.php.

Comment: Ok, you may need to have a look in the content.php file. In here you will probably see where the post markup is generated. Up where the post title is generated, you will probably see something like the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); You could put your author information in there

Comment: Thank you, after some searching I actually found it :D. Thank you very much for helping me to solve my problem.

Comment: No problem Vinnie - glad you found a solution!